# Replace comma separated values with code from another cell

Tags: excel

For each number (1 through 4) , I am assigning a code.I am inputting this data starting from first row (A1 through C4)

```
Number   Code   
 50000     L        
 80000     M      
 40330     L        
 40000     H
```

Input: Now, each person gets numbers separated by comma every week and my data is like this

```
Person     Week1                                               Week2
Person1    50000,80000,40000 (Lets assume A10 is the cell)    40330,40000(A11 is the cell)
```

My expected output:

```
Person     Week1     Week2
Person1    L,M,H     L,H
```

How can I find the comma separated values and substitute with the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Char(65) is same as "A"

Find function gives you number of digits till ","

Left functions is to find left number before ","

Right function is to find right number after ","

```
=CHAR(LEFT(A10,FIND(",",A10)-1)+64) & "," & CHAR(RIGHT(A10,LEN(A10)-FIND(",",A10))+64)
```

This will find the number of digits till "," then subtract 1 so it will be only first number before ","

Then Lenth of digits - number of digits till "," from the right side of the text will get you the second number

Comment: Thanks. Your solution for the dataset works great. But my actual data is like this. My number can be any 5 digit number with any type of code.  for example,   50000     L ,   84030   M,   43432  H.  Based on some logic, I assign letters to numbers. So I am trying to see how i can use find and get the value in the next column

Comment: Give me an example. 50000 L will be changed to what value? Because your question seems like number 1 is changing to A. So I am assuming those data will be changed to something?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. My data can be any 5 digit number having a code between L, M and H. For example, 50000 will have value as L (in the next column), 80000 can have value M (in the next column). So 50000 L and 80000 M are my reference table.. In my input table, if I have 50000, I should look up 50000 in my reference table and come up with answer L.  If my input table has 50000,80000, my output should be L, M

Comment: Will there be only 2 datas in one cell? or will there be more than 2?

Comment: There can be more than 2 data in a cell.

Comment: I've added another answer to the page. check it out and let me know if it works. I assumed Column A as 5 digit number.  Column B as Letter.   Column C as the input and You can put formula on any column

Answer (score 0):

Ok...before I start, this will be really really ugly :)

Below formula for the first letter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(INT(LEFT(C1,FIND(",",C1)-1)),$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")
```

Below formula for the second letter

```
& IFERROR("," & INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(INT(MID(C1,FIND(",",C1,6)+1,5)),$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")
```

Then you can copy and paste the second letter formula for the third letter and forth letter and so on.

for the third data, you have to change number "6" after "C1" in secound formula to "12" (Increment of 6)

Repeat the process as much as needed.

So When you combine them all together

It will look something like this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(INT(LEFT(C1,FIND(",",C1)-1)),$A$1:$A$4,0)),"") & IFERROR("," & INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(INT(MID(C1,FIND(",",C1,6)+1,5)),$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")& IFERROR("," & INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(INT(MID(C1,FIND(",",C1,12)+1,5)),$A$1:$A$4,0)),"")
```

The number 6 I mentioned was for digits 50000,(which has 6 digits)

If there is space after number (50000 ,) then you should number it increment of 7

Let me know for further questions